# How Create Users for jboss EAP 7 in another instance

Tags: java, linux, jboss7.x

How to create a user in a different standalone instance, for the Jboss EAP 7 application server?

I'm doing it like this:

`add-user.sh -sc standalone_02 -a -u userapp -p ****** -g guest`

why doesn't it recognize the standalone_02 instance?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: when I execute this command I get an error in a new window with WFLYDM0023 code that indicates the 'application-user.properties' files are not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely just need to create the files in that directory. Something like the following should work.

```
touch standalone_02/application-users.properties
touch standalone_02/application-roles.properties
```